# MySQL correct Case Statement to override first declared value

Tags: mysql, case

I have this case statement:

```
CASE 
WHEN CI.season = 1 THEN "Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 2 THEN "Early Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 3 THEN "Late Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 4 THEN "Dry Season"
WHEN CI.season = 4 and R.date_accessed > "2016-05-20 23:59:59" THEN "NULL"
ELSE "NULL" END as "Season" ,
```

How can I show that if season value is 4 and date accessed is > than "2016-05-20 23:59:59" should equal to NULL. Right now it is showing only "Dry Season". I think it only reads the first scenario. Thanks for the reply Guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CASE 
WHEN CI.season = 1 THEN "Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 2 THEN "Early Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 3 THEN "Late Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 4 and R.date_accessed > "2016-05-20 23:59:59" THEN "NULL"
WHEN CI.season = 4 THEN "Dry Season"
ELSE "NULL" END as "Season"
```

Or

```
CASE 
WHEN CI.season = 1 THEN "Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 2 THEN "Early Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 3 THEN "Late Wet Season"
WHEN CI.season = 4 THEN
    CASE WHEN R.date_accessed > "2016-05-20 23:59:59" THEN "NULL" ELSE "Dry Season" END
ELSE "NULL" END as "Season"
```

Comment: Second one is doing its job but it takes too long.. ;)